# Validating single value in array with Zend_Filter_Input

Tags: zend-framework

I'm trying to implement Zend_Filter_Input to validate if first value in array is not empty.

Here is my HTML:

```
 <input type="text"  name="Firstname[1]">
 <input type="text"  name="Firstname[2]">
 <input type="text"  name="Firstname[3]">
```

This code is not working:

```
   $validators = array(

   'Firstname[1]'    => array( 
                                    'NotEmpty'

                                     ));

  $input = new Zend_Filter_Input(null, $validators, $_POST);
```

Any hints?

Comment: I'm already using the $data array which actually is the $_POST with all fields from the input form. So updated the code example above. Is there a way to validate only specified field from Firstname array   or do I need to copy into the $data only the relevant fields for a validation process?

Comment: What does your $_POST array actually look like?

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to use an incompatible data type, here is an excerpt from the ZF1 reference that might help explain:

> You can specify ***input data*** as the third constructor argument. The data
>   structure is an ***associative array***. The keys are field names, and the
>   values are data values. The standard $_GET and $_POST superglobal
>   variables in PHP are examples of this format. You can use either of
>   these variables as input data for Zend_Filter_Input.

```
$input = new Zend_Filter_Input($filters, $validators, $data);
```

I hope you see the problem.

Maybe you could try:

```
<input type="text"  name="Firstname[1]" required>
<input type="text"  name="Firstname[2]">
<input type="text"  name="Firstname[3]">
```

as long as your using HTML5